# VB.net - Getting Data from an XML File

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to write a small program to get some data from an XML file which is already being used by another application (NOT MY OWN).

The XML Looks like this ...

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

sunjournal

  rvcmappings default="MISSING"

      rvcmap unitId="2" rvcnum="443" /  

      rvcmap unitId="3" rvcnum="103" /

      rvcmap unitId="5" rvcnum="701" /              

  /rvcmappings

/sunjournal
```

I am trying to use the below Code in VB to get the "rvcnum" for the UnitId of 5.

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
doc.Load("C:\BootDrv\Aloha\RptExport\GLMapping_Master.xml") 
Dim acc As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("sunjournal/rvcmappings/rvcmap[UNitId='5']/rvcnum").InnerText

msgbox(acc)
```

Can anyway point me in the right direction as I do not receive any Errors in Runtime just doesn't show the any Msgbox Data??

Many Thanks
Rob

Comment: There is no attribute called `UNitId`... it's called `unitId`.  XML is case-sensitive.  Also, attributes in XPATH must use the `@` symbol... so use `[@unitId='5']`.

Comment: Hi There I actually should have Cut n Paste the Code instead of re-writing. It doesn actually say UnitId.
I am actually getting an Error which I have found now is Object Ref not set to an instance on the doc Object, any ideas?

Comment: And please learn to format your questions correctly.  To use code, indent each line with 4 spaces at the start.  Please see the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the syntax you are looking for is:

```
node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//sunjournal//rvcmappings//rvcmap[@unitId='5']")
```

This will get you the element.  From there you can access the attribute:

```
node.Attributes("rvcnum").Value
```

Use these docs for some [more examples](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) as you work through your program.

Comment: Glad to help.  Enjoy your project!